# Prove by induction that $T(n) = T(9n/20) + T(n/2) + c$ is of order $O(n)$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am given the following equation:

$T(n) = T(9n/20) + T(n/2) + c$, where $c$ is a constant.

I am required to **prove by induction** that $T(n)$ is of the order $O(n)$ (Big-O).

I'm new to this topic and am not sure where to begin. Is the base case $T(0)=0$? Do I assume that $T(n)\in O(n)$ and then try to show that $T(n+1) \in O(n+1)=O(n)$?

Should I even begin to attempt expanding the expression (doesn't seem to be helping)?

\begin{align}
T(n) & = T(9n/20) + T(n/2) + O(1) \\
 & = T(9n/20) + T(9n/40) + T(n/4) + O(1) \\
 & = T(9n/20) + T(9n/40) + T(9n/80) + T(n/8) + O(1) 
\end{align}

---

The suggested solution begins with the following statements, which I cannot comprehend:

$T(n) \le T(n) + T(n) + c = 2T(n/2) + c$

$T(n) = T(n/2-1)+T(n/2) + c \le 2(2T(n/4)+c)+c = 2^2T(n/2^2)+(1+2)c$

$\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$T(n)=T\left(9n/20\right)+T(n/2)+c\tag{1}$$
$$ T(n)=T\left(\frac{10n-n}{20}\right)+T(10n/20)+c=T\left(\frac{10n}{20}-\frac{n}{20}\right)+T\left(\frac{10n}{20}\right)+c$$
$$\le2T\left(\frac{10n}{20}\right)+c=2T(n/2)+c$$
further more tight analysis is possible.